# Problem in rules of Firestore (collection group)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to get data from Firestore.
I have these structures for books in FireStore

```
Books --Book1.....name
             .....auteur
             .....user_id
             .....describe
      --Book2.....name
             .....auteur
             .....user_id
             .....describe
```

and use this code to get it

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup("Books")
    .get()
    .then(
      (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
```

I set these rules for group collection in the rules of Firestore.

```
 match /{path=**}/Books/{book} {
     allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
 }
```

And I set Firebase Authentication for this app
After compiling the app and logging in to the app
When I want to get the book I see this error

**The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.**

Comment: Your database structure doesn't really look like it requires a collection group query.  You are only showing one Books collection.  If that's the case, then you only need a normal query on that one collection.   Collection group queries are only required if you have multiple collections of the same name to query all at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting that the rule will filter only documents where the user's UID equals the document's `user_id` field.  That's not how rules work.  The documentation is clear that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  What your rule requires is that the query in your app must specify a filter on the `user_id` field with the value of the user's UID.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup("Books")
    .where("user_id", isEqualTo: uid)
```

Where `uid` is the user's UID.

This makes the query match the rule, so it is now only requesting documents that the rule has granted read access.